# Google Play store shows in-app-purchase status (how can i remove that)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

[image]

I am launching new Android App, however my app does not have any in app purchases. I don't remember where i have set this setting, I searched every detail for this App but did not find how to remove this setting. If anybody can let me know, where to check.

[Update]

It has anything related to Content ratings, i selected "Yes" here

[Content Ratings Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2JoC.png)

Answer (score 4):

When i updated (yes to no) in content ratings. In-app purchase was removed.

(As per below image i previously marked yes and now updated it with no)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2JoC.png

Thanks everybody for help.

Comment: I selected "NO" for digital goods in my app but "In-app purchases" is still there. Maybe now there is some other setting to update?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your AndroidManifest.xml at your declared permissions.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Likely need to remove:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, i dont have such setting in AndroidManifest.xml file. It seems something else is causing that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you marked that your app has In-App Purchases in the Google Play Console. Open the app in Console and uncheck the button which asks if you have any purchases in your application.

Or you should delete In-App Purchase dependency from your application source code Gradle file. It may be a solution if you have that dependency in the code.

Comment: I dont find such button in app settings or anywhere. Gradel dependency i will check and update here.

Comment: I see your message below. This button in content ratings was what I were talking about :)